# Convert parameterized sql to oracle package

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, code-generation, parameterized

I've a c# .net application that inserts records to oracle using parameterized sql. There are several such insert and I was wondering if there's any tool out there that could help me convert these to the Oracle Package?

e.g. One of the parametrized sql is

```
INSERT INTO SYSADM.MY_TABLE  
(ID, NAME, ADDRESS) VALUES 
(:id, :name, :address)
```

Thanks.

Comment: The tool you require is atop your shoulders....

Comment: Just a tip: When i have tons of insert to do, i put the data into an excel and with an expression i create an insert for each row. Fastand simple.

Comment: @MitchWheat, its a lot of conversion to do manually and very error prone.

Comment: @araknoid, I'm not asking to generate insert statements in excel.

Comment: @hyperkittie Sorry my fault for the comment above (misundertand the question), but I don't think that there is a Tool for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool that I know of.  However, if you have a text editor which supports regex in its Search'n'replace functionality it is quite simple to convert such statements into PL/SQL.

Alternatively we can generate code from the data dictionary.  USER_TABLES and USER_TAB_COLUMNS provied all the information needed to build PL/SQL APIs.

Steven Feuerstein has published an Oracle Code Generator which builds entire Table APIs very easily.  It was a bit contraversial back in the days, as some people don't like TAPIs and laso dome of the interfaces are open to SQL injection, but it's worth a look.  [Check it out.](http://www.toadworld.com/Downloads/QuestCodeGenUtilityFreeware/tabid/686/Default.aspx)